# C# Overloaded constructor cannot differ on use of parameter modifiers only

Tags: c#, constructor, parameters

I get the compiler error in the title with an error ID of CS0851 when I try and do this:

```
public class Cells {

    public Cells(params Cell[] cells) : this(cells) {}

    public Cells(Cell[] cells) { ... }
}
```

I know I can get around this by getting rid of the first constructor and requiring code to use the later constructor (forcing the conversion to an array where the constructor is being called) but I think that's not a nice outcome.  I understand why the compiler might have problems differentiating between the constructors with these similar signatures.

The question is: Is there some way I can actually get this to work?

```
   Cells c1 = new Cells(new Cell[] { new Cell(1), new Cell(2)});
   Cells c2 = new Cells(new Cell(4), new Cell(5));
```

This is using mono and is possibly a newbie question.

Comment: Remove second constructor.

Comment: The question is can I have both?  I know I can remove one of the constructors to work around the problem.  "I know I can get around this by getting rid of the first constructor and requiring code to use the later constructor"

Comment: I'm afraid, they can't exist both at the same time.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog I believe the reasoning is how will the complier know which constructor to use when given a Cell[]...obviously if it's using multiple Cell[] parameters then it would use the params option, but with one parameter it wouldn't know which to use

Comment: Why do you need both? First one can be called both ways.

Comment: Yeah .. I think you may be right Marcin.  I don't have a lot of experience with C# so  I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  It's a shame.. it's just not as pretty as it might be.  I could use a Factory method I suppose.

Comment: ok.. PetSerAl I shall give it a go.

Comment: Mono doesn't like the array calling convention with the params constructor.  "Best overloaded method has some invalid arguments".

Comment: Python has an array "unwrapping?" operator.. so e.g. foo(*some_array) would convert the array to a params array.

Comment: Mbdavis the first "params" constructor takes args of type Cell not Cell[] when you call it.  The compiler wraps the list of cells up into a list as  syntactic sugar (presumably using varargs or similar under the hood).

Comment: Side note: "forcing the conversion to an array where the constructor is being called" is very strange statement as both constructors will take arrays (and `params` will convert arguments to array at compile time...)

Comment: Alexei I'm no C# expert but I think the params statement takes Cell objects not Cell[] objects (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx for eg.)?  Perhaps I'm confused?  (At least when you call it).

Comment: @AaronLS: No, `params Cell[] cells` is the right syntax for a variable list of `Cell` arguments.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog: `params Cell[] cells` can accept a variable-length list of `Cell` arguments, or a single `Cell[]`.

Comment: If I only have the params constructor the call with the array won't compile.  All the upvotes for that approach makes me think I am missing something?

Comment: @dementedhedgehog Show the code that is not compiling and include the compiler error it gives you.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog: Well, your second call line has an extra `}` that I had to remove when writing the demo: http://rextester.com/GMFO43627

Comment: @Ben Voight.  It doesn't work for me.  Possibly down to a Mono bug ("feature")?  It's an oldish version of Mono

Comment: @dementedhedgehog: It also works just fine on Mono, see here: http://ideone.com/bgcytR  That site uses mono-3.10, according to the FAQ (but their FAQ is not trustworthy)

Comment: You did not include the error you get.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: He said he got "Best overloaded method has some invalid arguments" but hasn't showed the exact code that gave that error.

Comment: @Scott there is a lot of code (and it's in unity running over wine, so a hello world type example is difficult).   I've done something stupid (I'd changed the arg to List<Cell> to try and get around this.  Apologies to those of you who argued against me.   You were correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass both single items and arrays using the params constructor, you don't need two constructors.

```
using System;

public class Cell
{
    public Cell(int x) {}
}

public class Cells
{
    public Cells(params Cell[] cells) { Console.WriteLine("Called with " + cells.Length.ToString() + " elements"); }
}

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Test #1: ");
           Cells c1 = new Cells(new Cell[] { new Cell(1), new Cell(2)});
            Console.Write("Test #2: ");
           Cells c2 = new Cells(new Cell(4), new Cell(5));
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Run Code</kbd>](http://rextester.com/GMFO43627)

Comment: @BenVoigt swaped out the code in the answer to use your example program :), it does demonstrate it better.

Comment: Yeah.  PetSerAl, BenVoight and Scott Chamberlain all provided the correct answers in comments.  I can't see Bens answer to upvote it.   Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

How about a static constructor for your second case?

```
public class Cells
{
    public Cells(Cell[] cells)
    {

    }

    public static Cells getCells(params Cell[] cells)
    {
        return new Cells(cells);
    }
}
```

Its the simplest way I see.

Comment: But this is not needed.

Comment: I think the answer is that you can't do it.  (The compiler isn't clever enough to differentiate between the params and non params constructor signatures).  Using Factory methods is perhaps the nicest work around.

Comment: The answer is you don't  need to do it. You can pass arrays in to constructors decalred `params` without issue.

Comment: As I understood his question, he wanted to know if theres any way to have both methods. Now he knows. Of course theres no need to do so.

Comment: @Scott is correct.  You can do it the way he has suggested